# If the app contains two services, is both the services run on main thread

Tags: android, service

If two services are there in one app, is they both run on main thread or any worker thread.

Comment: Services always run on the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

A service is a Java object. Java objects do not run on threads. Methods run on threads.

The lifecycle methods of all services (`onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, `onDestroy()`) are called on the main application thread. It is your job to do any serious work on background threads. Those background threads might be provided to you (e.g., `IntentService`, `JobService`); if not, you need to create them yourself.